# Send a variable from a python file, to javascript, and then to a separate HTML file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension, with the main code being in python but I'm struggling. I've succeeded in sending information from the user inputted from the HTML side to the python script, but not the other way around. Here's what I have so far (or the code that seems to be the problem):

Python:

```
@app.route('/get_data', methods = ['POST'])
def get_data():
    taken = request.get_data()
    taken2 = taken.decode()
    print(taken2)
    strength = int(taken2)   #this works, I use this later in the code
    my_variable = 5                    #just for example 
    return jsonify(my_variable), 200
```

background.js (javascript)

```
function myAction(input) { 
    console.log("input value is : " + input.value);

        newish = input.value

        var xxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xxhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        xxhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_data");
        xxhttp.send(newish);


       //so sending newish here works, this shows up on my python console (strength becomes this)
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
    <script src="background.js" type="text/javascript">


    </script>     

       
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A Thing!</h1>

    <div style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">           
        <h3>Hello,</h3>
        <p>User input please? : </p>         
        <input id="name_textbox" />                   
        <button id="ok_btn" type="button">OK</button>
    </div>   

  </body>


</html> stuff
```

What I'm aiming for is for the my_variable to be accepted into the javascript file somehow, and then the html being able to access and display the contents of my_variable. I've tried looking around, but nowhere seems to have the exact thing I'm looking for (send python variable to separate html file for chrome extension). I'm at a bit of a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## **Better way of doing it**

Since you want to send the variable from python to html by reading the file, this is better than using the FS module in javascript.

example index.html code:

```html
<body>
    <h1>Hello, {first_header:}!</h1>
    <p>{p2:}, {p1:}</p>
</body>
```

python code for the above:

```py
newFileCode = open("index.html", "r").read().format(first_header='goodbye', 
                                         p1='World', 
                                         p2='Hello')
open("index.html", "w").write(newFileCode)
```

output in the HTML file:

```html
<body>
    <h1>Hello, goodbye!</h1>
    <p>Hello, World</p>
</body>
```

read more about file handling in python [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp)

## **PREVIOUS ANSWER**

You can parse the data using JSON. Although, you'll need a new Node.js module fs https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html. 
 
Once you've installed that module, you have to maintain two JSONs, one being a JS variable and the other being an external .json file.

Use this code to write in external JSON files in javascript:

```js
fs = require('fs');
var name = 'fileName.json';
var m = {"example": "HELLO"}
fs.writeFileSync(name, JSON.stringify(m));
```

Use this code to read an external JSON file in javascript:

```js
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(name).toString())
```

---

---

To get/read the data from the external JSON file in python use this code:

```py
import json
  
# Opening JSON file
f = open('fileName.json',)
  
# returns JSON object as 
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)
  
# Iterating through the json
# list
for i in data['emp_details']:
    print(i)
  
# Closing file
f.close()
```

You can edit the file from javascript and can read it in python using a while loop

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to this, but this sends the js variable to python right? I have a python variable I want to send to the HTML code, I've already been able to do it the other way (using XMLHttpRequest()). But if I have a python variable like my_varable, how do I get that to print to my HTML file?